# Get the iOS safe area width/height in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to get the width and height of the iOS safe area in Nativescript. I can't find any documentation on how this is done.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution already. I hope this helps somebody.

```
import * as application from "@nativescript/core/application";
import { Screen } from "@nativescript/core/platform";

let screenheight = Screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs;
let safeAreaTopInset = application.ios.window.safeAreaInsets.top;
let safeAreaBottomInset = application.ios.window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;

let safeAreaHeight = screenheight - safeAreaTopInset - safeAreaBottomInset;
```

Comment: Would this code throw an error on an android environment because `application.ios` is undefined?